# How can I hide my texts when my screen is locked?

Tags: ios, messages, sms

I had that option before and the recent update messed all my settings up:( now I can't hide my texts. I don't want people at work seeing my texts. I have my phone locked but everyone still can read them. I also don't have the option hide preview which was there before!

Answer (score 10):

In iOS 5, go to Settings > Notifications > Messages. Turn off 'View in Lock Screen'. It makes it so that iMessage/text message notifications don't show up on the lock screen.

Comment: I believe it actually says "Show Preview". So it should be Settings > Notification Center > Messages > Uncheck Show Preview